# How to Make Silverlight control appear over another one?

Tags: silverlight

I have two instance of controls. When I open the second one it will appear over the first one, like two folders in Windows opened at the same time.

How do I add functionality so that when I click on the first one, it makes it **appear over** (like zindex) the second one?

Thanks

Comment: What kind of container are your controls in?

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

Add A **Canvas**, set its Z-Index, in your **canvas** place your **UserControl1**

Add **Another Canvas** set its primary Z-Index, in that **canvas** place your 2nd **UserControl2**.

OnClick Events of Canvases, you can easily set their z-indexes to show at the top.